# React JS class component const = with multiple conditions

Tags: reactjs

I would like to return different buttons depending on what conditions are met.
This is in react js class component.

I would like to achieve this:

```
if (credentials.username === username) {

if paused === false {
 <MyButton
 tip="Pause Job"
 onClick={this.handlePause}
 >
Pause
 </MyButton> 


} else {


 <MyButton
 tip="Un Pause Job"
 onClick={this.handleUnPause}
 >
Unpause
 </MyButton> 

}
} else { //credentials.username is not equal to  username show null
null
}
```

Comment: Please spend the extra 2 minutes to format your code. It's so much easier to help that way..

Comment: What exactly is your question? What problem are you facing? What does your code not do that you expect it to do? These should all be included in your question. However, it looks like you're simply missing a `return` statement inside of each conditional.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```js
{credentials.username === username && !paused &&   <MyButton
 tip="Pause Job"
 onClick={this.handlePause}
 >
Pause
 </MyButton> }

{credentials.username === username && paused &&   <MyButton
 tip="Pause Job"
 onClick={this.handlePause}
 >
Pause
 </MyButton> }

{credentials.username !== username &&   <></> }
```